# Asymptotic growth of number of ways to distribute $10$ balls into boxes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, balls-in-bins

> What is the polynomial asimptotic bound of $
> (a_n)_{n=10}^\infty$, where $a_n$ represents the number of ways to distribute $10$ identical balls into $n$ non-identical boxes, such that there are no two nonempty boxes with the same number of balls?

There are, of course, ${{10+n-1}\choose {n-1}} = \Theta (n^{10})$ ways to distribute $10$ identical balls into $n$ labeled boxes.
I guess that $a_n=\Theta(n^4)$, since when $n$ is large, almost all boxes remain empty; so the "closest to empty" configuration is the one in which there exist four boxes with $1,2,3$ and $4$ balls respectively. Showing that this is a lower bound is easy, but I am not sure how to show that it is an upper bound (if it is indeed the correct answer).

Comment: Given $n$ large enough, there are only a few fixed patterns. So $a_n$ is just a sum of binomial coefficients.

Comment: It is physically difficult to do this, and much easier to drop the balls one-at-a-time into the boxes, so with $n^{10}$ equally likely ways of doing this.  But this just multiplies the number of ways of getting the $1,2,3,4$ pattern by a constant $\frac{10!}{1!2!3!4!} = 12600$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be written as a sum over the partitions of $10$ into distinct positive integers; these can be counted by hand and they are given by

$$4 + 3 + 2 + 1, 5 + 3 + 2, 5 + 4 + 1, 6 + 3 + 1, 6 + 4, 7 + 2 + 1, 7 + 3, 8 + 2, 9 + 1, 10$$

so there are $10$ of them (and this can be verified on [the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000009)). Given such a partition we can consider the number of ways to distribute its parts among $n$ labeled boxes and of course the answer is ${n \choose k}$ where $k$ is the number of parts. So the exact answer is

$$a_n = {n \choose 4} + 4 {n \choose 3} + 4 {n \choose 2} + {n \choose 1}$$

with asymptotic $a_n \sim \frac{n^4}{4!}$ as expected.